# iOS Swift navigationBar and tabBar same hex but different color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to get the same color for both my navigationBar and tabBar.  I'm using the same hex # for both but my navigationBar seems to be darker than my tabBar?  I'm not sure why....is there some property that needs to be changed to either the tabBar or navigationBar?

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor =  HomeVC.hexStringToUIColor("#0998EE")        
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.barTintColor = HomeVC.hexStringToUIColor("#0998EE")
```

Comment: try this self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false;

Comment: @NANNAV didn't work. The navigationBar is still darker than the tabBar

Answer (score 1):

You might try unchecking the translucency property for the `UINavigationController` in the inspector on the storyboard, or `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false` in code.

Comment: @pbbush25  didn't work.  The navigationBar is still darker than the tabBar